# Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'loginUserWithUsername'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

Prior to this I was working in objective C. Now I need to code my project in swift language. While making a web service call using AFNetworking classes I created a class named as FSAPI in which I am creating following 2 blocks

```
typedef void (^requestCompletionBlock) (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject);
typedef void (^requestFailureBlock) (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error);
```

and following methods for login

```
//****************** Login Service **********************//
- (void)loginUserWithUsername:(NSString *)username
             andPassword:(NSString *)password
             andGrant_type:(NSString *)grantType
     withCompletionBlock:(requestCompletionBlock)completionBlock
         andFailureBlock:(requestFailureBlock)failureBlock;
```

Now I don't know in swift how can I make this call. I have already created bridging header file and imported FSAPI.h into it.

```
    FSAPI.sharedClient().loginUserWithUsername("", andPassword: "", andGrant_type: "", withCompletionBlock: requestCompletionBlock() {
     AFHTTPRequestOperation, id in

        //to do

        }, andFailureBlock: requestFailureBlock () {

        })

+ (id)sharedClient {
    static FSAPI *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:baseServerURL]];
    });
    return sharedClient;
}
```

Please somebody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show how the `sharedClient()` is defined. Currently it's typed as AnyObject and this is not what you want.

Comment: sharedClient() definition added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the blocks in swift is treated as closure,

```
FSAPI.sharedClient().loginUserWithUsername("", andPassword: "", andGrant_type: "", withCompletionBlock: { (operation, response) -> Void in {

    //to do in success case 

    }, andFailureBlock: { (operation, error) -> Void in {

        //to do in error case 

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Replace id with instancetype.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
    static FSAPI *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:baseServerURL]];
    });
    return sharedClient;
}
```

Comment: [FSAPI .sharedClient() .loginUserWithUsername("", andPassword: "", andGrant_type: "", withCompletionBlock: <requestCompletionBlock (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void {
            
            }>, andFailureBlock: requestFailureBlock (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void {
            
            })];

Can you please tell me what is wrong with above line of code?